# si​tem​ap-​tax​-po​st_​tag​.xm​l not found - webmaster tools

Tags: wordpress, seo

I'm a newbie in webmaster tools. I get 3 errors in webmaster tools:

1.2: We encountered an error while trying to access your Sitemap. Please ensure your Sitemap follows our guidelines and can be accessed at the location you provided and then resubmit.

*General HTTP error: 404 not found
Sitemap: smsbaz.org/sitemap-pt-post-2015-05.xml

HTTP Error: 404

*General HTTP error: 404 not found
Sitemap: smsbaz.org/sitemap-tax-post_tag.xml

HTTP Error: 404
[image]

3:We encountered an error while trying to access your Sitemap. Please ensure your Sitemap follows our guidelines and can be accessed at the location you provided and then resubmit.

*General HTTP error: 404 not found
HTTP Error: 404

[image]

where is my wrong ? how can I solve these errors ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved !

Because I used `Yoast` plugin. I removed it and install `Google XML Sitemaps` and `All In One SEO Pack` then you must fetch same URL's from your webmaster tools(`googlebot-fetch`).